# SQL Server query inner join query doesn't work

Tags: sql-server

I have a table similar to below in sql server 2005

```
date_column | field1 | field2 
1 June 2012 | xyz    | 53
1 June 2012 | abc    | 87
2 June 2012 | xyz    | 81
3 June 2012 | xyz    | 54
3 June 2012 | abc    | 53
3 June 2012 | abc    | 54
4 June 2012 | mmn    | 53
4 June 2012 | xyz    | 54
4 June 2012 | mmn    | 54
4 June 2012 | mmn    | 55
3 June 2012 | abc    | 55
3 June 2012 | adf    | 86
3 June 2012 | asd    | 33
```

I want to find all field1 values which has corresponding field2 values '53', '54' and '55'.  within the same date so output should be as below :

```
date_column | field1 | field2
3 June 2012 | abc    | 53
3 June 2012 | abc    | 54
3 June 2012 | abc    | 55
4 June 2012 | mmn    | 53
4 June 2012 | mmn    | 54
4 June 2012 | mmn    | 55
```

I tried the below sql code with inner join but it doesn't work

```
select date_column, field1, field2 from table1
inner join (select date_column, field1, field2 from table1 where field2
in ('54',  '55')) as table2
on table1.date_column = table2.date_column and
table1.field1 = table2.field1
where field1 in ('53', '54', '55')
group by date_column, field1, field2
order by date_column, field1, field2
```

Comment: are you getting an ambuiguous column error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work? You might be overcomplicating this or I am misunderstanding the problem

```
SELECT field1, date_column FROM table1
WHERE field2 in ('53', '54', '55')
GROUP BY field1, date_column
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field2) = 3
```

[Here is the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bec9e/1)

You say you only need to find field1, so this should work, but if you need all columns, then you can do this:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
JOIN
(
SELECT field1, date_column FROM table1
WHERE field2 in ('53', '54', '55')
GROUP BY field1, date_column
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field2) = 3
) AS MoreThan1
 ON Table1.field1 = MoreThan1.field1 and Table1.date_column = MoreThan1.date_column
```

[Here is the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bec9e/3)

OR, just add a WHERE if you only want the all columns for those in the 53-55:

```
WHERE Table1.field2 in ('53', '54', '55')
```

[Another Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df08e/1)

Comment: @user1449596 With the fiddles? I get your exact expected result

Comment: thanks justin...it works...finally I could have output the way I want...
both your code and Kevin code displays same output which I want.

Comment: I forgot to inform you...i just changed your line to
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field2) = 3).....to make it work

Comment: @user1449596 Great! I have modified this, and if it helped you, please dont forget to accept this as the answer

Comment: & kelvin & justin
I have one more small question on this, I want to display field2 values in this order '54', '53', '55'.

    I tried this code but it doesn't work
     (order by (case when field2 = '54' then '1' else 0 end),
     date_column, field1, field2)

Comment: @user1449596 I did this and it works for what you want: `ORDER BY Table1.Field1, CASE Table1.Field2 WHEN 54 THEN 0 WHEN 53 THEN 1 WHEN 55 THEN 2 END `

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want:

```
select *
from t
where field1 in (select field1
                 from t
                 where field2 in ('53', '54', '55')
                 group by field1
                 having max(date) = min(date)
                )
```

The subquery finds the field1 ids that match your condition.  The outer query just selects all the data for those ids.

I think I originally misread the requirement.  You want any date where this is true.  This version should do that:

```
select *
from t join
     (select field1, date
      from t
      where field2 in ('53', '54', '55')
      group by field1
      having count(distinct field2) = 3
    ) a
    on t.field1 = a.field1 and t.date = a.date
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon

This query doesn't work either. please note my date column is text data/type.

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't work?  The type of the date column doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I don't know exactly but your query displays records where field2 is not 53 or 54 or 55..it just shows remaining field2 values.

Comment: sorry, somewhere it also displays '53' along with other field2 values. But nowhere I can see '54' or '55' in field2.

Comment: @Gordon..thank you too..
Though I can't make it work with your code, I got to learn something from you. Can you please explain why and when we use max(date) = min(date)? It might help me in the future....

Comment: The original code used max(date) = min(date) because I misread your requirement.  I thought you wanted all three to be on exactly one date.  Instead, you want all dates that have all there.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 1 table (table1), correct?  If so, no join is required:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE field2 in ('53', '54', '55');
```

Comment: This will not work because it displays all field2 records which has either '53' or '54' or '55' or both...

I will try query given by Justin and update shortly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  You can GROUP BY date..?  I was simply pointing out that with 1 table, no join is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.date_column, t1.field1, t1.field2
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT t2.date_column, t2.field1
    FROM table1 t2
    WHERE t2.field2 IN ('53', '54', '55')
        AND t2.date_column = t1.date_column
        AND t2.field1 = t1.field1
    GROUP BY t2.date_column, t2.field1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT field2) = 3)
ORDER BY t1.date_column, t1.field1, t1.field2
```

Comment: Thanks kevin
but this code also doesn't work...Please note the value 53 may occur several time for each date for each field1 value, but it can have only one '53', '54' and '55'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "it can have only one '53', '54' and '55'".  I have updated the query to allow for duplicate rows so give it another try.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Your new code finally worked for me.

Even Justin new code worked. Thanks a lot to every one.

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.date_column, table1.field1, table1.field2 
from table1 
inner join (select date_column, field1, field2 
            from table1 
            where field2 in ('54',  '55')) as table2 
    on table1.date_column = table2.date_column and table1.field1 = table2.field1 
where table1.field1 in ('53', '54', '55') 
group by table1.date_column, table1.field1, table1.field2 
order by table1.date_column, table1.field1, table1.field2
```